# Alter multiple tables' columns length

Tags: sql, database, oracle, orm, ddl

So, we just found out that 254 tables in our `Oracle` DBMS have one column named **"Foo"** with the wrong length- `Number(10)` instead of `Number(3)`.

That `foo` column is a part from the PK of the tables.
Those tables have other tables with forigen keys to it.

What I did is:

1. backed-up the table with a temp table.
2. Disabled the forigen keys to the table.
3. Disabled the PK with the `foo` column.
4. Nulled the `foo` column for all the rows.
5. Restored all the above

But now we found out it's not just couple of tables but **254 tables**.

Is there an easy way, (or at least easier than this) to alter the columns length?

P.S. I have DBA permissions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an easier way to generate the scripts that you want, use the system tables [`user_tables`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/statviews_2117.htm#REFRN20286) and [`user_constraints`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/statviews_1046.htm#i1576022) to dynamically generate the DDL. The downside is that this requires downtime. Also note that I use the [`truncate`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10007.htm#SQLRF01707) command rather than `delete`, which should be faster.

Assuming a simple table that looks like:

```
create table a ( 
   foo number(10)
 , bar number(10)
 , constraint pk_a primary key (foo)
 , constraint fk_a foreign key ( bar ) references a(foo )
  );
```

This unlovely looking query

```
select cmd
  from ( 
select table_name
     , 1 as stage -- Just used to order by at the end.
     , 'create table ' || table_name || '_backup as select * from ' 
                      || table_name || ';' || chr(10) as cmd
       -- chr(10) is LF
  from user_tab_columns -- View of all columns
 where column_name = 'FOO'
   and data_precision = 10 -- Length of the number
 union all
select table_name
     , 3 as stage
     ,  'truncate table ' || table_name || ';' || chr(10) -- Remove all data
       || 'alter table ' || table_name 
               || ' modify ( foo number(3));' || chr(10)
       || 'insert into ' || table_name || ' select * from ' 
            || table_name || '_backup;' || chr(10)
       || 'drop table ' || table_name || '_backup;' as cmd
  from user_tab_columns
 where column_name = 'FOO'
   and data_precision = 10
 union all
select ut.table_name
     , 2 as stage
       -- Disable the constraint
     , 'alter table ' || uc.table_name || ' disable constraint ' 
            || uc.constraint_name || ';' || chr(10) as cmd
  from user_constraints uc -- All named constraints
  join user_tab_columns ut
    on uc.table_name = ut.table_name
 where ut.column_name = 'FOO'
   and ut.data_precision = 10 
   and constraint_type = 'R' -- Foreign Key constraints (see link)
 union all
select ut.table_name
     , 4 as stage
     , 'alter table ' || uc.table_name || ' enable constraint ' 
          || uc.constraint_name || ';' || chr(10) as cmd
  from user_constraints uc
  join user_tab_columns ut
    on uc.table_name = ut.table_name
 where ut.column_name = 'FOO'
   and ut.data_precision = 10
   and constraint_type = 'R'
       )
 order by stage
```

Will produce the following:

```
create table A_backup as select * from A; -- Create your backup
alter table A disable constraint FK_A; -- Disable FKs
truncate table A; -- Remove all data in the table
alter table A modify ( foo number(3)); -- Reduce the size of the column
insert into A select * from A_backup; -- Replace all the data
drop table A_backup; -- Drop the backup
alter table A enable constraint FK_A; -- Re-enable FKs
```

Due to the column `stage`, this won't be done table by table but stage by stage so that all the constraints will be disabled at the same time, which will avoid problems. If you're scared (I would be) then remove the `drop` of the `_backup` tables from the query; this means that whatever goes wrong you're safe.

If you're running this in SQL*Plus you also want to include `whenever sqlerror exit` so that if there's a problem, for instance no more tablespace, you don't truncate things that you haven't backed-up. It might almost be worth running it stage by stage so that you know that everything has completed correctly.

I would suggest testing this on a different user with a few tables to ensure that it does everything you need.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please add comments to the _"unlovely looking"_ code above. I don't want to run DDL queries I don't fully understand.

Comment: I've tried to make it more understandable... And  added a few cautionary notes :)

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate your help and effort. One last thing, what is `chr(10)` doing? I've never seen such a thing in a query.

Comment: No problem I do similar things regularly! It's just a line feed (ASCII 10), `chr()` encodes it. It means that the statements which are concatenated together to avoid having loads of unions are on different lines when the results are printed.

Answer (score 1):

What we have done is:

```
CREATE TABLE <table_name_backup> as SELECT *  <table_name>;
DELETE <table_name>;    
ALTER TABLE <table_name> MODIFY (Foo NUMBER(3));
INSERT INTO <table_name> SELECT * FROM <table_name_backup>;
DROP <table_name_backup>;
```

For all the tables.

Comment: No cascade delete (for example) unwanted behaviours ? Seems quite dangerous (at first glance, but I may miss something).

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus. Ohh, yes, I had to disable all the foreign keys in the referenced tables. I'll add that to the answer shortly. {And it was I who missed something... ;) }

Answer (score 0):

Your solution works but is a lot of work and implies downtime.

Since physically a `NUMBER(3)` is exactly like a `NUMBER(10)` with a stronger constraint you could add `CHECK` constraints and get the same logical restriction without downtime:

```
LOOP
   ALTER TABLE <table_name> ADD CONSTRAINT <table_foo_chk> CHECK (foo < 1000);
END LOOP;
```

Comment: The disadvantage of this is that all inserts and updates will have to check against that constraint forever more.

Comment: @ben: the single check constraint produces an undetectable amount of overhead compared to the massive amount of work (generating redo/undo, getting blocks from cache, etc, etc, etc...) implied by an update/insert.

Comment: It doesn't help me because I have them to be `NUMBER(3)` because  we started to use `Entity Framework` and it maps some to `short` and some to `int`. Thanks anyway.