# Is there a way to change all char(1) columns to number(1) columns in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

We use `char(1)` columns to store Boolean values in Oracle, where the value is either `"1"` or `"0"` to represent true or false.  However, I want to change these to `number(1)` columns, where the value is either `1` or `0`.  It seems you cannot change the type of this column if there are already existing values in the table.  So I have to do something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE TPM_TRAININGPLANSOLUTIONS DROP CONSTRAINT SYS_C0010178;
ALTER TABLE TPM_TRAININGPLANSOLUTIONS RENAME COLUMN ISMARKERCOMPLETION TO ISMARKER_CHAR;
ALTER TABLE TPM_TRAININGPLANSOLUTIONS ADD (ISMARKERCOMPLETION NUMBER(1) NOT NULL);
UPDATE TPM_TRAININGPLANSOLUTIONS SET ISMARKERCOMPLETION = ISMARKER_CHAR; -- This takes about 10 min
ALTER TABLE TPM_TRAININGPLANSOLUTIONS DROP COLUMN ISMARKER_CHAR; -- Also very slow

ALTER TABLE TPMDBO.TPM_TRAININGPLANSOLUTIONS
    ADD ( CONSTRAINT SYS_C0010178
    CHECK (ISMARKERCOMPLETION in (0,1))
    NOT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE VALIDATE );
```

However, we have dozens of these columns in our database.  Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to do that? reason?

Comment: @shahkalpesh - Good question.  The .NET Entity Framework will map `number(1)` to a Boolean, where-as `char(1)` gets mapped to a String.

Comment: The message is quite clear, I think that what you're doing is the only solution...

Comment: @shahkalpesh don't you prefer to run bitwise operations on numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no simple way to do what you are doing; you could using the system tables to generate the DDL for you but you still need to know the column names. However, there are simpler ways to map it to a number, without changing anything.

Firstly, you need to ensure that your columns are actually the values you've assigned.

```
ALTER TABLE TPMDBO.TPM_TRAININGPLANSOLUTIONS
    ADD ( CONSTRAINT chk_TPM_TRAININGPLANSOLUTIONS_IMC
    CHECK (ISMARKERCOMPLETION in ('0','1'))
    NOT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE VALIDATE );
```

You can then either create a [virtual column](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/virtual-columns-11gr1.php) on the table:

```
alter table tpm_trainingplansolutions add ( 
   ismarkercompletion_num generated always as (to_number(ismarkercompletion)) virtual
   );
```

Or a view on top of the tables, which [casts](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions023.htm#SQLRF00613) that particular column to a NUMBER.

Either would probably result in a little less work, but now much as you need to know the column names. Do what you're doing and ensure your database is correct.

As an aside, you're creating a constraint with the prefix `SYS_`, please don't do this... create constraints with meaningful names and don't try to mimic Oracle.

If you want to change *all* CHAR(1) columns you can use [USER_TAB_COLUMNS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/statviews_2103.htm#REFRN20277) to identify those columns that have this characteristic and use it to generate your DDL for you, e.g.

```
select 'ALTER TABLE '
        || table_name 
        || ' RENAME COLUMN '
        || column_name 
        || ' TO ' || substr(column_name, 1, length(column_name) - 5) 
        || '_CHAR ;'
  from user_tab_columns
 where data_type = 'CHAR'
   and data_length = 1
```

You'll probably have to use [USER_CONS_COLUMNS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/statviews_1044.htm#REFRN20045) as well...

Comment: Yea, I have no idea who came up with those constraint names.  They're used everywhere in the database though, I assume they were originally created through some sort of tool.  We also use like `TABLEFOO_FK1`, `TABLEFOO_FK2`, `TABLEFOO_FK3` for all our foreign keys.  Sigh.

Comment: It looks like the Oracle default @Mike, which if you're creating in the DDL yourself could, potentially, be dangerous. It implies people created constraint in the table DDL without naming them...

Comment: I guess I can add *rename all constraint and FK names to something descriptive* to my To Do list.  Thanks for your answer, though, this helps a lot!

Comment: Just found [what I wrote](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12278474/alter-multiple-tables-columns-length/12280989#12280989) for someone else @Mike, it's identical to what I've written above save with a few more stages in and doing something slightly different... may be of use...

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of columns i think what you should do is

1. disable all constraints of the base table
2. `create as select` a new table from the base table with the desired column data types
3. copy the constraints from the base table
4. replace the base table with the new table

Altering the table one column at a time can cause a lot of issues like fragmentation and chaining. To keep the db healthy you'll be forces to rebuild it any way. So, You might as well do it the right way from the start.

Comment: A CTAS means stopping _all_ work on the DB though... you can't risk any DML being performed on the base table...

Comment: and altering columns means locking the entire table.